# create layout programmatically and save it as bitmap android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have code to create view programmatically like this ,

```
splash.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    processFromDatabase();
                }
            });
```

splash is my parent view , and this is processFromDatabase Code

```
private void processFromDatabase() {

        createLayoutBook("food_name", "80000", "food_des","", 2);



            Bitmap bmp = merge();
            saveToLocal2(bmp);


    }
```

and this is my code for createLayoutBook ,

```
    private void createLayoutBook(String food_name, String food_price,String food_des, String path, int tag) {
            Log.e("create layout book", "Create layout book");
            RelativeLayout root_2book = new RelativeLayout(c);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp_a = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 120, c.getResources()
                                    .getDisplayMetrics())));
            rlp_a.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
            root_2book.setLayoutParams(rlp_a);
            root_2book.setBackgroundColor(c.getResources().getColor(R.color.krem));

    RelativeLayout layout_detail_2book = new RelativeLayout(c);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rdet = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rdet.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, layout_a_2book.getId());
            rdet.setMargins(20, 3, 0, 0);
            layout_detail_2book.setLayoutParams(rdet);

TextView tv_nama_2book = new TextView(c);// nama
        tv_nama_2book.setId(id_book);
        id_book = id_book + 1;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tv_nama = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tv_nama_2book.setLayoutParams(tv_nama);
        tv_nama_2book.setTextSize(20);
        tv_nama_2book.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        tv_nama_2book.setText(food_name);
        Log.e("food name", food_name);
        getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0).edit().putString("food_name", food_name).commit();

        TextView tv_des_2book = new TextView(c); // des
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tv_des = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tv_des.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv_nama_2book.getId());
        tv_des.setMargins(0, 3, 5, 0);
        tv_des_2book.setLayoutParams(tv_des);
        tv_des_2book.setTextSize(12);
        tv_des_2book.setTextColor(c.getResources().getColor(R.color.hitam));
        tv_des_2book.setText(food_des);
        Log.e("food des", food_des);
        getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0).edit().putString("food_des", food_des).commit();

        layout_detail_2book.addView(tv_nama_2book);
        layout_detail_2book.addView(tv_des_2book);


root_2book.addView(layout_detail_2book);
splash.addView(root_2book);
```

and this is code for change this layout to bitmap

```
public Bitmap merge() {

        View v1 = splash;

        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap merge = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);


        return merge;
    }
```

But why , it return with black screen , like my layout that I created before not save or missing , any solution?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want something like this:

```
public Bitmap merge() {

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(...);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    splash.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```